# Can we impute missing values in two column by finding the correlation in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6vcH.png)

What is the best way to impute Nan values in this table?

can we sum the STD rate and HIV rate and get a correlation and then impute based on that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question doesn't provide adequate context to understand what you are trying to achieve. The simplest way to impute is to just drop any rows containing Nan values. Does this satisfy your needs? Or are there other problem specific goals and constraints? If so, can you elaborate?

Comment: I am sorry for my naive question. I am learning data cleaning and preparation. In this table there  are multiple NaN values which need to be dealt with. I am not sure what method to use to impute the missing values. Is there a way apart from using central tendencies?

Comment: There are missing values in both columns simultaneously so I don't see how correlation help you to impute here. Using something like mean of column is ok in my opinion. You can also take mean of state if there is enough data for each. Also you can take a look to https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html. There are some simple imputing strategies.

Comment: I ended up doing the same. I calculated their mean and grouped  them by states and wrote a function to impute missing values.